# iOS equivalent of Android's MediaProjection permission

Tags: android, ios

On android I can use MediaProjection permissions to get permissions to take a screenshot of my phones screen from a background thread.  Is this possible in iOS?  Is there some permission request to give the thread access to the entire screen in order to take a snapshot?

Comment: Are you expecting to take a screenshot of your app's current screen in the background or the system's screen? Because the latter isn't possible on iOS due to sandboxing, but the former is quite simple so long as you have something that allows your app to be resumed briefly in the background (like a silent push notification)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm looking to get a Screenshot of the System screen.

Comment: Yeah sorry as far as I know that's not possible, you can snapshot as far as the root window of your own app but that's it I'm afraid.

Comment: @CamHart did you get any solution for this?

Comment: No, what I found was even with the latest ios updates to support screen sharing the user has to manually open settings and enable the app to access the screen.